# Como mapear una lista que está dentro de un objeto JSON?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, fetch

Supongamos que tenemos esta consulta, que retorna un JSON:

https://santqbus.santcugat.cat/consultamv.php?q=GetLinea&idgrupo=null&idlinea=26

Sé como mapear los datos que están en un "primer nivel" como por ejemplo ID_GRUPO o ID_LINEA, pero como podría ahora mapear los datos que se encuentran en la lista "TrayectosDet" (los datos que me interesan se encuentran a su vez dentro de otra lista llamada "parada") e inyectarlos en un modelo de datos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo esta lectura para que puedas entender un poco mejor como parsear json más complejos: https://medium.com/@carlosAmillan/parseando-json-complejo-en-flutter-18d46c0eb045

Ten en cuenta que cada dato que retorna puede ser un Map o un List, cuando tenga esto al inicio `{` es un map, cuando tenga `[` es un List, de acuerdo a eso puedes ir bajando de niveles.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```dart
  void _loadData() async {
    final response = await http.get('https://santqbus.santcugat.cat/consultamv.php?q=GetLinea&idgrupo=null&idlinea=26');
    final List result = jsonDecode(response.body);

    for (Map item in result) {
      final idGrupo = item['ID_GRUPO'];
      print(idGrupo);
      final trayectos = item['TrayectosDet'] as List;
      for (Map subItem in trayectos) {
        final parada = subItem['Parada'];
        final desc = parada['DESC_PARADA'];
        print(desc);
      }
    }
  }
```